# fail message upon boot up on kubuntu "failed to reset device"

Tags: startup

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rlmO.jpg

I recently began getting this message every time I boot my pc,  I use kubuntu 18.04 encrypted drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a problem with the touchpad, when you see this message you won't be able to use the touchpad. The way to fix it is by going to the login screen and enabling your touchpad(fn+f7 on acer) restart and then it will work again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a linux mint 21 user and I've faced that error too. 
 My touchpad & touchscreen stopped responding every time I reboot my system.

**Here is what I did to solve the problem**:

- I made sure I've `Enabled` my touchpad in the first place: 
  **control panel** > **mouse and touchpad** > **touchpad tab** > from the drop down menu select **Enabled**.- which was already enabled-.
- I have a dual boot, so I tried testing my touchpad on the other OS (Windows, in my case), to eliminate the possibility of having a hardware fatigue. Luckily, it was working fine there.
- I tried to update my current touchpad driver as mentioned in the [mint community](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=281790) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-_geY913JQ), but that did work on me unfortunately.
- Lastly I downgraded my kernel from `5.15.0-58-generic` to `5.15.0-47-generic` and the error is gone and my touchpad worked again! 
  **update Manager** > **view** > **Linux Kernels** > **install a new kernel version** > **reboot** > in your Grub menu select "**Advanced options"** > from the new menu **pick your new kernel** that you want to use > **Enter**. 
  see [advanced options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJHSk.png)

**To check the current kernel version you are using:**

- you can go back to `Linux Kernels` and you can see an `active` label beside the used one, **remove** the previous activated kernel so you don't need to choose **Advanced options** every time you boot.
- Or, in your terminal `$ uname -r`. 
  see [active kernel version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JKce.png)